# Publish Django project to windows host

Tags: python, django, iis, web-deployment, windows-server-2008

I have completed my web page and I want to publish it on windows server, but I am getting HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Youtube video link she watched for broadcast [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpFU16KrJcQ)

This is the error I get

[image]

Comment: Error code  0x80070005 means application pool doesn't have permission to folder which contain site and .py handler. You need to change the application pool identity to local system or administrator. Then add IIS AppPool to security tab of folder properties.

Comment: @BruceZhang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888007/error-occurred-while-reading-wsgi-handler-error can you see this error

Comment: Yes, I can see. But I think we can solve the question in this thread firstly.

Comment: I solved the problem, sir, I published the site. But when I want to publish a different site, I got an error

Comment: Can you post the correct solution in this thread? This will help others with same question to find solution quickly

Comment: this is how i solved the problem i gave write and read permissions to python folder and problem solved