# Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Error

Tags: python, django, iis, webdeploy

when I want to open the django project, I encounter such an error. My django projects are live on the same server, but I encountered such an error on the last site I opened.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <add name="Python FastCGI" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\python39\python.exe|c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
 </handlers>    
 <tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests>
    <clear />
  </traceFailedRequests>
 </tracing>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="umy.wsgi.application" />
<add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="umy.settings" />
<add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation tempDirectory="C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\tmp" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

The error I get is about;

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler
raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb))
ValueError: "umy.wsgi.application" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
File ".\umy\wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
return WSGIHandler()
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
self.load_middleware()
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
module = import_module(module_path)
File "c:\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'htmlmin'



StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please show the `MIDDLEWARE` list in `settings.py`

Comment: htmlmin When I installed the library, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow below steps to fix the issue.**

Step 1.Click the `Handler Mappings`, find `FastCgi`, click `Edit`, modify  the `Executable(optional)` value with the virtualenv path.

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project_name\virtualenv\Scripts\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project_name\wfastcgi.py
```

Step 2.Open `FastCGI Settings` like below.

[image]

Step 3.Click `Environment Variables`, and add below to the collection.

```
Name: WSGI_HANDLER
Value: django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()


(Django porject path）
Name: PYTHONPATH Value:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project_name


(Prohect settings path）
Name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
Value: project_name.settings
```