# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' when setting up Flask server with IIS 6.2 with FastCGI

Tags: python, iis, fastcgi

I have a very basic Flask server that sits on a file named app.py in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stockmanager

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, This is the Flask App in IIS Server."

app.run()
```

I have set up everything including permissions for IUSR and IIS_IUSRS

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <!-- Required settings -->
       <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="app.app" />
       <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stockmanager" />
     </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Flask Handler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\env\Scripts\python.exe|C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
       
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
     </configuration>
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER")) File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\wfastcgi.py", line 616, in get_wsgi_handler raise ValueError('"%s" could not be imported%s' % (handler_name, last_tb)) ValueError: "app.app" could not be imported: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\StockManager\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]]) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' StdOut: StdErr:
```

From my understanding by pointing WSGI_HANDLER to app.app it means import my app from the app.py file but for some reason it does not find it, any tips would be helpful!

Comment: [Did you take a look at this question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888007/error-occurred-while-reading-wsgi-handler-error)

Comment: @Torvalds Hi, I checked that question out and seems like everything is configured like it should on my end